# Datas from mysql database don't display on website

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, type-conversion, latin1

I started my Project with **UTF8 Database** for the development. At the time of project completion, my Professor gave me the database of type **Latin1**. Because of Type Conflicting my project is not working properly, result my server side code doesn't access the database.

I tried much conversion: My Professors database into UTF8, but it failed.
Still I’m facing the issue. Kindly assist me in this regards.

Thank you !

Comment: Here is a [link](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/djcp/2010/01/convert-mysql-database-from-latin1-to-utf8-the-right-way/) which might be useful to you.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be changing the connection encoding. But this needs more detailed information on what exactly goes wrong, etc..

Comment: What are you seeing?  (Give us an example.)  What is the declaration of the `CHARACTER SET`?  (Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  How are you connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a charset converter like **[MySQL charset converter](https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1280)**

This PHP script can be used to convert your MySQL database tables from latin1-to-UTF8 while retaining the integrity of all internal multibyte characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! The datas are displayed but when I have an accented letter the rest of the content is not displayed. I have only a part of datas who are displayed.

Comment: will converting to utf fix your problem? if then, you may try it.

Comment: It fix a part of the problem. Only a part of the datas are displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;

replace charset_name with latin1

You can also change columns individually

ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY ColumnName ColumnType CHARACTER SET latin1;

Comment: If u have workbench try opening options file and set server collation to latin1